# LPTHW Ex.43 Changing a class initial parameter

Tags: python, function, class, methods

I'm trying to get over one last hurdle for this exercise and I can't figure it out! I can't grasp my head around the play() method in the class Engine. Specifically "next_screen_name".

Looking at the code below:

```
class Engine(object):

def __init__(self, scene_map):
    self.scene_map = scene_map

def play(self):
    current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()
    last_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene('finished')

    while current_scene != last_scene:
        next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
        current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)

    # be sure to print out the last scene
    current_scene.enter()

class Map(object):

scenes = {
    'central_corridor': CentralCorridor(),
    'laser_weapon_armory': LaserWeaponArmory(),
    'the_bridge': TheBridge(),
    'escape_pod': EscapePod(),
    'death': Death(),
    'finished': Finished(),
}

def __init__(self, start_scene):
    self.start_scene = start_scene

def next_scene(self, scene_name):
    val = Map.scenes.get(scene_name)
    return val

def opening_scene(self):
    return self.next_scene(self.start_scene)

a_map = Map('central_corridor')
a_game = Engine(a_map)
a_game.play()
```

If you run the code above and "current_scene.enter()" returns 'death' from the enter() method. The code will go ahead and return the next scene which is Death().

But what I don't understand is, if you originally set "a_game" with an initial parameter of "a_map" which would be 'central_corridor'; how does the initial "scene_map" change to "death"??

Link to full code here:

http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex43.html

Thanks in advance a ton everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going through LPTHW and have been looking over this game for the last few days to try and grasp what is going on. I'm obviously not very experienced when it comes to OOP so take this all with a grain of salt.

What I found most difficult to grasp was that scene_map, used in the play() method, is just an instance of the Map class which takes a variable, aMap, which is a Map Object.

```
a_map = Map('central_corridor')
a_game = Engine(a_map)
a_game.play()
```

The Below comments on the code try to show the steps that happen as the above code is executed to start the game.

```
class Engine(object):

    # Step 3 - This requires a variable with a Map object to be passed in.
    # Each Engine 'has-a' Map to navigate the scenes. this is passed into 
    # the engine class through an object scene_map 
    def __init__(self, scene_map)
        self.scene_map = scene_map

    # Step 4 - Once an instance of the map and scenese has been initialized
    # the play() method of the Engine class can be called to start the game.
    # First the current_scene attribute is created by running the 
    # opening_opening scene method from the Map class. This will be used 
    # once we enter the while loop to start the game. the last_scene attribute
    # is also set at this point to be used in the while loop so the program
    # knows when you have finished or won the game.
    def play(self):
        current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()
        last_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene('finished')

        # The while loop runs while the game is in play. In the first
        # iteration the current_scene attribute is set above with the 
        # start scene. After that the current_scene is re-set to the 
        # return value at the end of every scene object or 'death' when
        # you die which takes you to the Death object.
        while current_scene != last_scene:
            next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
            current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)

        # be sure to print out the last scene
        current_scene.enter() 

class Map(object):
    # sete scenes dictionary property for Map class
    scenes ='central_corridor': CentralCorridor(),
        'laser_weapon_armory': LaserWeaponArmory(),
        'the_bridge': TheBridge(),
        'death': Death(),
        'finished': Finished(), 
    }

    # Step 1
    # Each Map 'has-a' scene(s) The scene objects are stored in the scenes dict
    # The start scene passed in as a string will corrispond to an object 
    # by going through the scenes dict. This will be done in the 
    # next_scene method of the Map class
    def __init__ (self, start_scene):
        self.start_scene = start_scene

    # Step 2a
    # Looks up the scene string in dict(scenes) and returns the 
    # object for that scene.
    # This will be passed into the Engine Class to move to the next scene
    # through the val attribute
    def next_scene(self, scene_name):
        val = Map.scenes.get(scene_name)

    # Step 2b
    # This is a special instance to look up the starting scene based on 
    # the string 'start_scene' passed through the __init__ Metho to start
    # the game. 
    # This will be passed into the Engine to start the game
    def opening_scene(self):
        return self.next_scene(self.start_scene)
```

Getting to you question on how it changes to the Death() object. Once you die in whatever scene you die in it returns 'death'  which is interpreted in:

```
current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)
```

I hope this helps a little. It was a good exercise for me to try and explain it.